# I have some problems with l3file

Tags: expl3

I am a beginner in LaTeX3，and create a command `test`, for write some token in myfile `test.aux`,this is mwe

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \iow_new:N \l_tmpa_file
  \iow_open:Nn \l_tmpa_file{test.aux}
  \NewDocumentCommand{\test}{+m}
  {
    \iow_now:Nn \l_tmpa_file{#1}
  }
  \file_input:n{test.aux}
  \test{aaaaa}
  \test{bbbbb}
  \test{ccccc}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I want input myfile at the beginning, I use notepad to read my file，

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

but my `\file_input:n{test.aux}` doesn't work, I use `\iow_show:N \l_tmpa_file`,

```tex
\file_input:n{test.aux}
\iow_show:N \l_tmpa_file
```

the `test.aux` is empty.
My needs are as follows

1. I can compile twice, the first time to write to the file and the second time to read the file
2. input needs to come first

I need help, thanks!

Comment: If you want to read and *append* files; LuaLaTeX has an excellent interface. If you are open to use it, we can try doing this with Lua scripting.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use lualatex, where do I need to learn? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `\iow_open:Nn` says:

> Opens `⟨file name⟩` for writing using `⟨stream⟩` as the control sequence for file access. If the
> `⟨stream⟩` was already open it is closed before the new operation begins. The `⟨stream⟩` is
> available for access immediately and will remain allocated to `⟨file name⟩` until a `\iow_close:N` instruction is given or the TeX run ends. *Opening a file for writing clears any
> existing content in the file (i.e. writing is not additive).*

(emphasis mine)

So you effectively remove the file content when you run `\iow_open:Nn`. (Also you forgot to run `\iow_close:N`). You can solve this by moving the `\iow_open:Nn` to *after* you read the file.
For example you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \iow_new:N \l_tmpa_file
  \NewDocumentCommand{\test}{+m}
  {
    \iow_now:Nn \l_tmpa_file{#1}
  }
  \file_input:n{test.aux}% We haven't called \iow_open:Nn yet, so the content of test.aux is still there.
  \iow_open:Nn \l_tmpa_file{test.aux}% Now we no longer need the old content and can start to overwrite it.
  \test{aaaaa}
  \test{bbbbb}
  \test{ccccc}
  \iow_close:N \l_tmpa_file
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

(You might also want to use another file extension than `.aux` to avoid interference from LaTeX's `.aux` files)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I still don't quite understand, can you make a mwe to make it easier for me to understand, thank you again！